# Как настроить работу контактной формы на всех страницах?

Tags: html, wordpress

Всем привет! Вот такой вопрос: есть контактная форма на сайте, она взята у Webdesignmaster'а из уроков, вернее сам PHP скрипт, прикрутил ее на лендинги - все отлично работает, сообщения доходят. Добавляю ее же в Wordpress caйт, работает, но только на главной странице, хотя сама форма и все скрипты для ее работы находятся в футере, который на всех страницах тоже есть, но тем не менее работает все это дело только с главной. Что на Openserver'e что с хостинга работает все точно так же. Может это какая то особенность wordpress? Или просто я не догоняю?

[image: JS код]

[image: PHP код]

Answer (score 1):

Вообще в wordpress я бы посоветовал использовать Contact Form 7.

Если же вам очень нужен именно этот скрипт, то оформите его в фугкцию в файле functions.php темы ForasLump и ajax сделайте по другому. Нужно читать, например, тут - http://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: Наверное стоит поразбираться на будущее, чтобы потом проще было, большое спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Все нашлось решение, всего то "/" надо поставить в URL к файлу mail.php))